# Stop opening popup when form is invalid

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I need to prevent popup(overlay) showing when error tips showing. Here is my code,

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"  id="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#overlay"><i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i> Submit</button>
```

```js
function myvalidationfunction(){
  // can I do this here? 
}

document.addEventListener('invalid', (function(){
      return function(e){
          //prevent the browser from showing default error bubble/ hint
          // e.preventDefault();
          // optionally fire off some custom validation handler
           myvalidationfunction();
      };
})(), true);
```

```html
<div class="modal fade product_view" id="overlay">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
       <img width="200" height="200" src="{{ asset('frontend/images/loading2.gif') }}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

But nothing seems working.How to stop popup showing in this situation?

Comment: Can you add little bit more context? What error message? Browser default validation?

Comment: The snippet does not work.

Comment: Are you trying to show more than one modal (popup)?  You'd need to add a bit more context.  Simple answer to not showing a popup, is not to create one.  The modal created above is just the opposite.  Why prevent is the question?

Comment: The way you are initiating the modal bypasses the form entirely.  Try opening the modal via JS initialization instead of `data-toggle`. At that point you can ensure it only opens when you want it to.